# How to repeat rotation from Scipy in C ++ (Eigen or Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, scipy, eigen

I have a rotation done with Scipy, I would like to replicate it in C++ using the Qt library (Or Eigen as a last resort). How can this be done? I tried using QQuaternion::fromEulerAngles,but the output is completely different Euler angles. Can you tell me how can I repeat this composition of rotations?

```py
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
r = R.from_euler('xyz', [84.8715505575325, -18.6072424802551, 106.28342910934], degrees=True)

print(r.as_matrix().transpose())
>>array([[-0.26573263,  0.90971132,  0.31907911],
       [ 0.003305  , -0.33011727,  0.94393414],
       [ 0.9640411 ,  0.25188866,  0.08471633]])

r2 = R.from_euler('XYZ', [90, 180, 90], degrees=True)
r3 = r2 * r

print(r3.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True))
>> array([ 0.19642533, 15.41049032, 19.32819967])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eigen and easily create rotation objects from Euler angles (see https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialGeometry.html#TutorialGeoEulerAngles). However, intrinsic/extrinsic systems have to be handled manually and requires a little bit more effort.

Using C++11 and development/master branch of Eigen:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include "Eigen/Core"
#include "Eigen/Geometry"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

long double operator"" _deg(long double x ) 
{ 
    return M_PI * x / 180; 
} 

int main()
{
    std::cout.precision(8);

    Eigen::Quaterniond r, r2, r3;

    // 'xyz' - extrinsic rotation -> z*y*x 
    r =  Eigen::AngleAxisd(106.28342910934_deg, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ())
        * Eigen::AngleAxisd(-18.6072424802551_deg, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY())
        * Eigen::AngleAxisd(84.8715505575325_deg, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitX());
    
    std::cout << r.matrix().transpose() << std::endl << std::endl;

    // 'XYZ' - intrinsic rotation -> x*y*z
    r2 = Eigen::AngleAxisd(90.0_deg, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitX())
        * Eigen::AngleAxisd(180.0_deg, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY())
        * Eigen::AngleAxisd(90.0_deg, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ());
    
    r3 = r2 * r;

    // 'xyz' - extrinsic rotation -> z,y,x (reversed to obtain x,y,z)
    std::cout << (r3.matrix().eulerAngles(2,1,0).reverse() / M_PI) * 180 << std::endl;

    return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
 -0.26573263   0.90971132   0.31907911
0.0033050049  -0.33011727   0.94393414
   0.9640411   0.25188866   0.08471633

0.19642533
  15.41049
   19.3282
```